# Parse Error XML using Element tree in Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

New to Python and having issues converting to XML from a URL source. Tried quite a few ways to fix the code but am stuck. Any suggestions would be very helpful!

The program errors at below at 'xtree = ER.parse(fhand)'

ERROR:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Simeon\Desktop\Py4e\ex13_1.py", line 12, in <module> xtree = ET.parse(fhand) File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1222, in parse tree.parse(source, parser) File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 580, in parse self._root = parser._parse_whole(source) xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0`

CODE:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen

fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('https://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml')
sum = 0
for line in fhand: 
    sum = sum + len(line)
print(sum)

xtree = ET.parse(fhand)
xroot = xtree.getroot()

xlist = xtree.findall()
print(len(xlist))
lst = xtree.findall('comments/comment')
print('count:' , len(lst))

flist = [] 
for item in lst: 
    num = item.find('count').text
    flist.append(num) 

for i in range(0, len(flist)): 
    flist[i] = int(flist[i]) 

print(sum(flist))`
```

Tried converting to string but ER.parse required a bytes like object. I've also had a lot of httpresponse errors and am unsure why

Answer (score 2):

`fhand` is a file handler. When you count the length of the response, you move the cursor to the end of file. So you have nothing more to parse... You have to seek the pointer at the beginning of the file using `fhand.seek(0)` but you can do better using headers of `HTTPResponse`.

Rewritten code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen

fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('https://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml')
print(f"Content-Length: {fhand.getheader('Content-Length')}")

xtree = ET.parse(fhand)
xroot = xtree.getroot()

lst = xtree.findall('.//comment')
print(f"Count: {len(lst)}")

flist = [int(item.find('count').text) for item in lst]
print(f"Sum: {sum(flist)}")
```

Output:

```
Content-Length: 4189
Count: 50
Sum: 2553
```

**Alternative** using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) if you want to do data analysis:

```
# pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_xml('https://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml', xpath='.//comment')

print(f"Count: {len(df)}")
print(f"Sum: {df['count'].sum()}")
```

Details:

```
>>> df
           name  count
0        Romina     97
1        Laurie     97
2         Bayli     90
3        Siyona     90
4        Taisha     88
5        Alanda     87
6       Ameelia     87
7     Prasheeta     80
8          Asif     79
9          Risa     79
10           Zi     78
11       Danyil     76
12       Ediomi     76
13        Barry     72
14        Lance     72
15       Hattie     66
16        Mathu     66
17        Bowie     65
18       Samara     65
19      Uchenna     64
20       Shauni     61
21      Georgia     61
22        Rivan     59
23        Kenan     58
24       Hassan     57
25         Isma     57
26  Samanthalee     54
27        Alexa     51
28        Caine     49
29        Grady     47
30         Anne     40
31        Rihan     38
32       Alexei     37
33        Indie     36
34    Rhuairidh     36
35    Annoushka     32
36        Kenzi     25
37        Shahd     24
38       Irvine     22
39        Carys     21
40         Skye     19
41        Atiya     18
42        Rohan     18
43        Nuala     14
44        Maram     12
45        Carlo     12
46      Japleen      9
47     Breeanna      7
48       Zaaine      3
49        Inika      2
```